# If $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are the roots of $px^2 + qx + q=0$,

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

If $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are the roots of $px^2 + qx + q=0$, prove that: 
$$\sqrt {\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta}} + \sqrt {\dfrac {\beta }{\alpha }} + \sqrt {\dfrac {q}{p}}=0$$.

My Attempt:

$$px^2+qx+q=0$$
Then,
$$\alpha + \beta = \dfrac {-q}{p}$$
$$\alpha. \beta=\dfrac {q}{p}$$

..

Comment: There are several untold assumptions in the statement of the question. Obviously $\alpha,\beta,p \ne 0\,$ for the fractions to exist. What are the other assumptions, particularly about some of those being real, or having the same sign, or otherwise what is the definition of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ being used in the complex case.

Comment: It makes sense to assume $p,q \neq 0$, in which case $\alpha,\beta \neq 0$. So that's fine. But even with that, there will necessarily be something weird going on here. Because if $p,q$ are real and either root is positive then $-p/q>0$; in this case $pq<0$ and so only one root is positive. If $p,q$ are not real then of course the third term is complex. So there are complex numbers floating around somewhere. Where are they?

Comment: Sorry, I should say, if *both* roots are to be positive then $-p/q>0$ must hold, but then $pq<0$ so that only one can be positive.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: You prove: $\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right)^2 = \left(-\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{q}}\right)^2 \iff \dfrac{(\alpha+\beta)^2- 2\alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta} + 2 = \dfrac{p}{q}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate??

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}+\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{\alpha\beta}=\frac{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha-\beta)}{\alpha\beta}=\frac{-q/p(\alpha-\beta)}{q/p}$

Now, $\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right)=\frac{(\alpha/\beta)-1}{\sqrt{\alpha/\beta}}=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta\cdot \sqrt{\alpha/\beta}}$

$\therefore \left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}+\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right)=-\beta\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}=-\sqrt{\alpha\beta}=-\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}$

$\therefore \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}+\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}+\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}=0$

Comment: In real numbers, the square root is non-negative. In complex numbers, the real part of the principal value of the square root is non-negative. How do you reconcile that with the sum of $3$ square roots being $0\,$?

Comment: @dxiv, ha ha..., nice point, you opened my eyes,  but sorry I can't prove that.

Answer (score 1):

(*Followup on previous comment, but too long to post as another comment.*)

The conclusion does not hold true in general. Consider for example the case $\,p=q=1\,$, where the roots of $\,x^2+x+1=0\,$ are in fact the cube roots of unity:

$$
x^2+x+1=0 \;\;\implies\;\; \alpha=\frac{-1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\,,\;\beta=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{1}{\alpha}=\alpha^2\
$$

Then $\,\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{1}{\alpha}=\beta\,$ and $\displaystyle\,\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \alpha\,$. Assuming that $\,\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}\,$ denotes the [principal value of the complex square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Square_root) (which is one of the "*untold assumptions*" that my first comment asked about, still unanswered), $\displaystyle \,\sqrt{\frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}} = \frac{1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}\,$, and it follows that:

$$
\sqrt {\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta}} + \sqrt {\dfrac {\beta }{\alpha }} + \sqrt {\dfrac {q}{p}}=\sqrt{\beta}+\sqrt{\alpha}+1=\frac{1 - i \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}+1 = 2 \ne 0
$$

Comment: Also note that as I said in my own comment, no matter what these expressions involve complex numbers. Because even if both roots are real, they necessarily have different signs.

Comment: @Ian Right. Maybe I should drop the `in general` part from my `does not hold true in general` but I'd rather wait for the OP to clarify/salvage the question, first.