# If one root of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be the square of the other.

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

If $a \neq 0$ and if one root of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is the square of the other, prove that: $$b^3+a^2c+ac^2=3abc.$$

My Attempt:
Given:
$$ax^2 + bx + c=0$$
Let $\alpha $ and $\beta $ be the roots of the equation.
$$\alpha + \beta = \dfrac {-b}{a}$$
$$\alpha . \beta = \dfrac {c}{a}$$
According to the question:
$$\alpha = \beta^2 $$

Comment: What if $a=0\,$? If your question relies on additional assumptions, please spell them out.

Comment: @dxiv, There are no more assumptions. The question is exactly the same what I have typed.

Comment: If $a=0, b=1, c=-1$ then the only root is $x=1$ which is obviously its own square. However $b^2+a^2c+ac^2 = 1 \ne 0 = 3abc\,$, so the conclusion you propose doesn't follow.

Comment: @dxiv, What is the meaning of quadratic equation if  $a=0$?

Comment: Where was `quadratic` mentioned before this last comment? All I am getting at is that's important that you make sure to give the *full* context to a question in order to elicit unambiguous answers (same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398735/if-alpha-and-beta-are-the-roots-of-px2-qx-q-0)).

Comment: @dxiv, I hope I have tagged the question as quadratic makes sense.

Comment: Don't mean to turn this into an argument, it was just a suggestion for how to get more focused, better overall answers. Tags are not part of the body of the question. Anyway, the objection is moot after your latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we have $$\dfrac ca=\alpha\beta=\beta^3$$

$$-\dfrac ba=\alpha+\beta=\beta^2+\beta$$

Cube both sides using $$(p+q)^3=p^3+q^3+3pq(p+q)$$

Replace the values of $\beta^3,\beta^2+\beta$

Comment: Cubing both sides of which equation?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., Not equation, but the relation : $$-\dfrac ba=\beta^2+\beta$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\alpha + \beta = \dfrac {-b}{a}$$
$$\alpha . \beta = \dfrac {c}{a}$$
Substitute
$$\alpha = \beta^2$$
into previous equations,

$$a(\beta^2+\beta) = a\beta(\beta+1) = - b\tag{1}$$

$$a\beta^3 = c\tag{2}$$

Cube equation $(1)$,

$$a^3 \beta^3 (\beta^3 + 3 \beta^2 + 3 \beta + 1) = -b^3$$
Using equation $(2)$,
$$a^2 c (\beta^3 + 3 \beta^2 + 3 \beta + 1) = -b^3$$

$$a c (a\beta^3 + 3a\beta( \beta + 1) + a) = -b^3$$

Using equation $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$a c (c - 3b + a) = -b^3$$

$$ac^2-3abc+a^2c=-b^3$$

$$b^3+ac^2+a^2c = 3abc$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: 
$$\left(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \Rightarrow$$
$$b^2-2ac+ab=(a-b)\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \Rightarrow$$
Squaring and then dividing both sides by $4a$ will prove the claim.